# How do I add hash elements to another hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I do not seem to be able to add items to a hash.

I have the following method that has a hash passed in and the intent is to pass out a new hash made from the original. I have verified that the key is a string and the other two elements are floats. b_name, lat and lng all print to the logs when I request.

```
def construct_paint_hash(list)
    full_list = Hash.new
    num = 100
    list.each do |thing|

        puts num
        b_name = thing["name"]
        puts b_name
        lng = thing["longitude"]
        lat = thing["latitude"]
        full_list["#{b_name}"]=[lng, lat]
        # full_list[:dsfsd] = "dsfdsfds"
        num +=100 
    end
    return full_list
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 377ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:42:in `[]'
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:42:in `block in construct_paint_hash'
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:39:in `each'
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:39:in `construct_paint_hash'
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can I see the code calling `construct_paint_hash(list)`?

Comment: `lat = get_lat()`

 `lng = get_lng()`

`thing_search = HTTParty.get(construct_location_search(lat,lng))["data"]`

`thing_location_hash = construct_paint_hash(thing_search)`

`puts construct_paint_hash(thing_location_hash)`

Comment: sorry about the commenting disaster

Comment: I can't tell which call is causing the problem.  You call it multiple times in what you gave me.  But the one that is most suspicious to me is the last one where you pass `thing_location_hash` into `construct_paint_hash` right after assigning the return value of `construct_paint_hash` to `thing_location_hash` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: You sort of nailed it. You said that I called it multiple times. I thought "this guy is crazy!" as soon as I saw the code I have been staring at for an hour... I removed the puts statement that was really put in just for testing and it works. put it in the answer below and I will check it off as solved if you want

Comment: I thought it looked okay :)  YAY!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems okay, but you can use the following code `snippet`. I assume your `list` `params` as following

```
list = [{"name" => "dhaka", "longitude" => 23.44, "latitude" => 24.55}, {"name" => "usa", "longitude" => 23.44, "latitude" => 24.55}]
```

Then rewrite your `construct_paint_hash` as following

```
def self.construct_paint_hash(list)
    data = list.collect { |l| {l["name"] => [l["longitude"], l["latitude"]]} }
    return data.inject(:merge)
end
```